# Issues retrieving all venues managed by user

Tags: foursquare

I sent this off to api@foursquare.com over a week ago, but haven't heard anything back so thought I'd try here as well.

The issue I seem to be having is that I have a user that should manage 600+ locations, but when I create an app for them, then an oauth token, that token doesn't actually allow access to all the venues managed by that user.

I have tried verifying this using the /venues/managed API, and can confirm that the tokens I'm creating manage different venues.

We've done this through Apigee, and using the same credentials the token we're getting back will not consistently give us access to the same number of venues.

Is there a way to ensure the token I create will manage the correct number of venues?

Comment: Can you clarify "that token doesn't actually allow access to all the venues managed by that user" - what actions is the user unable to perform on the venue if you're seeing all of the venues in the /venues/managed API?

Comment: @enc_life - the issue is that the tokens we're generating don't seem to provide us with access to all the same locations (venues) we can see that this user manages in the foursquare web interface. It's not that they are limited in what they can do, they seem to not have access to ALL venues.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset your tokens at https://foursquare.com/developers/app/CLIENT_ID/reset and try to logging in again with the correct credentials.

You shouldn't get different oauth tokens if you logged in the same user on multiple devices - be sure that you're using the same credentials across devices.